# Get uncombined union of contiguous range objects

Tags: excel, vba

Consider this excel macro :

```
Dim Ra1 As Range, Ra2 As Range, RaUnified As Range

Set Ra1 = Range("B2:D4")
Set Ra2 = Range("E2:K4")

Set RaUnified = Union(Ra1, Ra2)

MsgBox RaUnified.Address(False, False) 
' Result: "B2:K4", but I'm searching a way to get the "B2:D4, E2:K4" not combined range

' Apply border formatting to each subranges in "one shot" :
RaUnified.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
```

I want to know if it is possible to get an uncombined union of Ra1 and Ra2, and **the solution should not use** `Range("B2:D4, E2:K4")`.

I just want to know if there is some other function/method that `Union` to get the same result as `Range("B2:D4, E2:K4")` unifying `Ra1` and `Ra2`.

(The purpose is to build a very large union of range objects dynamically and apply formatting to it in one shot, for performance optimization).

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it's possible? You could build it up using a sequence of strings "B1:B3" etc.

Comment: I don't understand you question (what should I try ?). I have tried to use Union(..., ...), and this function combines the ranges ... Address concatenation can do what I want to do, but it does not answer the question about the ability of expand a range dynamically without combination. String concatenation, like repeating `.Cells(i, j).Address` can reduice the performance.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand yours. What do you mean by "expand a range dynamically without combination"? Have you considered the answer below?

Comment: Having a Range object containing B1:B3, I want to know if it is possible to extend this range to be "B1:B3, C1:D3", and not "B1:D3" (result of union). And that all without string concatenation.

Comment: No I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep separate ranges would be to store a collection or dictionary of the discrete ranges you want to use. It's slightly more unwieldy than the code you want but you can store contiguous ranges this way. The downside is you would need to iterate through each range to apply the formatting as opposed to the 'one-shot' you would like.

> In a Class Module called 'RangeCollection'

```
Option Explicit
Private myDictionary As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set myDictionary = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(ByRef rng As Range)
    If Not myDictionary.Exists(rng.Address) Then myDictionary.Add rng.Address, rng
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(ByRef rng As Range)
    If myDictionary.Exists(rng.Address) Then myDictionary.Remove rng.Address
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Double
    Count = myDictionary.Count
End Property

Public Property Get Reference() As Object
    Set Reference = myDictionary
End Property
```

> Then in a module you can add a collection and iterate through the ranges to format them...

```
Public Sub TestUnionRange()
    Dim RngColl As RangeCollection: Set RngColl = New RangeCollection
    RngColl.Add Range("B2:D4")
    RngColl.Add Range("E2:K4")

    Dim Coll As Object: Set Coll = RngColl.Reference()
    For Each Item In Coll.Keys()
        Range(Item).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Comment: Interessant. But the result is not a Rande object. And like you say, it won't be adapted to my usage. I'm just surprised that excel can internally build a discontinued selection when it comes from the Range() reference string argument and VBA "can not", sadly.

Answer (score 0):

`Union` will always combine contiguous ranges to one range. But you can still have a border in between by setting the inside vertical border: `Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlMedium`

For example:

```
Sub UnionBorders()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2")

    Dim MyRange As Range

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To 100 Step 4
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Union(ws.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iRow + 2), ws.Range("C" & iRow & ":C" & iRow + 2))
        Else
            Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, ws.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iRow + 2), ws.Range("C" & iRow & ":C" & iRow + 2))
        End If
    Next iRow

    ws.MyRange.Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlMedium
    ws.MyRange.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
End Sub
```

Alternative by concatenating the addresses:

```
Sub ConcatBorders()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2")

    Dim MyRangeAddress As String

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To 20 Step 4
        If MyRangeAddress = vbNullString Then
            MyRangeAddress = ("B" & iRow & ":B" & iRow + 2) & "," & ("C" & iRow & ":C" & iRow + 2)
        Else
            MyRangeAddress = MyRangeAddress & "," & ("B" & iRow & ":B" & iRow + 2) & "," & ("C" & iRow & ":C" & iRow + 2)
        End If
    Next iRow

    ws.Range(MyRangeAddress).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
End Sub
```

But note that this only works for short addresses up to 256 characters. If it exceeds that limit it will fail.

Comment: Thank you for you workaround. But this just works for my very specific example. If I want to format Range("B1:B3,C1:D3"), for example, the vertical border between C and D should not be formatted.

Comment: Then you have 2 options: Either you concatenate the strings with `&` sign like I showed in my alternative (note that this works only to an concatenated address of maximum 256 characters). Or you cannot do it in one action and must do each action by its own.

Comment: OK, the the answer is no. It is not possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Alsatian yes that's what I said in my first sentence: *"Union will always combine contiguous ranges to one range."*

Comment: Understood. I was just wondering if there was another function, or Range method which can help to build some uncombined range.